# Unable to use opencv python in replit even after installation showing -- missing configuration file: ['config.py']

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, replit

> ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py'].
> Check OpenCV installation

trying to use opencv python for image formatting and video playing but its showing error. I tried to reinstall open cv python but didn't work...

Comment: which version of opencv are you using? what's your python version? also show us the code where you're facing the error

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)